# Windows 7 Activation during image deployment

Tags: windows-7

We currently have 40 machines that are being upgraded to Windows 7 Enterprise. One machine will need to have software installed on them, and then imaged and deployed to the other 39 machines. The client has purchased Volume Licenses for these machines and we will be using MAK's for activation.

With MAK keys, you can use the same key on multiple machines. These keys deduct from a pool of activations kept in the VLSC. If we are going to be using these keys on multiple machines can we activate it on the image machine, and deploy the activated machine, or would we have to deploy the unactivated image to all 39 other machines and activate them individually?

We are also doing this for Microsoft Office, I assume the process is similar.

Comment: It is to note that these machines are the exact same hardware, so doing such an image deployment would work.

Comment: You can also setup an automatic activation server.  Saves a lot of time when I imagine 200+ units

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sysprep
You can put the product key inside of the unattended.xml

sysprep /generalize
You may or may not need /oobe

When the sysprep'ed machine is started up it will re-detect all the hardware.  You will still need to load drivers for unique hardware, but there should be no show-stopper errors.

For example load nvidia driver and have an ATI card well your desktop will just come up in standard VGA mode until you load the correct drivers.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend looking at the Volume Activation Management Toolkit. It can be used to assist with MAK keys, the KMS (Key Management Service) if you are using it, and handles the OS as well as Office.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825141.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Most likely if you image an activated windows install onto a new machine it will go "out of tolerance" and need reactivating.

You may want to consider setting up a kms server and using that instead of mak keys. There are two advantages to this.

1. It makes it harder for rouge employees, theives etc to steal your keys.
2. You don't need to ring up MS and ask for more activations.

AIUI if you do use a kms and image machines you need to "rearm" the activation system immediately prior to imaging so each machine gets a different ID. Otherwise the kms server won't be able to tell the machines apart and wont reach it's activation threshold.